# UrlBuilder for apache sling

Tags: apache, bundle, aem, sling

I am looking for Apache Sling Api to build url and links. I have found a URLHandler and LinkUrl but i should install Adobe cq as bundle and this is not what i want.

Can any one recammand an API for URL? Thanks

Comment: Can you pls explain what you mean by building url and links ? Some example code that you're trying may help other people look at the issue.

Comment: http://wcm.io/handler/url/apidocs/io/wcm/handler/url/UrlHandler.html : something like that, this is for adobe cq, but i use only sling for this project

Comment: I don't have experience with wcm.io but [this](http://wcm.io/) says that it is an open source project and you should be able to include this [library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.wcm/io.wcm.handler.url/0.5.0) as a dependency in your project. yes/no ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the URL, you can maybe have a look at Adobes Templating Language called "HTL" or "Sightly". There you can build urls like this.

```
<a href="${currentPage.path @selectors='mySelector', extension='json'}>...</a>
```

you can also attach request parameters by generating a map either in a Java class oder JavaScript and then add the `@query='myModel.requestParameterMap'`

I hope this will help you.